# Visual Studio - debugging with PDB but missing type info

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I have a project built in **VS 6.0**, now I have to debug it remotely in **VS 2010**.

I am able to browse the source correctly, create a breakpoint and trace through lines, inspect simple types, but not complex data types. It looks as it didn't load them.

I had been able previously to debug with **WinDbg**, there I can read complex types, but have another (not really understand what) problem with inspection...

I have also tried to debug in **VS 2013**, where I can't even open **PDB**, it says that **PDB** can't match executable.

I must say that **PDB** is exact match of an **EXE** recently made, but in VS 6.0.

So I'm asking if someone have experience debugging with PDB, am I missing something? Is it possible that I'm using an old PDB which don't have type information?

Update:

When I open **pdb** file in Notepad, it looks that the symbols that debugger cannot find is really missing from **pdb**. So it happen that, from the same source file, some global variable names appear in **pdb**, and some not. Plus the debugger says that it cannot find symbol for complex type, even if it exists in **pdb**. The source code is not written in respect to new C++ standard, so it cannot be compiled in VS 2013, maybe that have effect.

Answer (score 0):

The modules window (Ctrl-D, M) is a good place to understand whats going on.

Right-click the module/dll that you expect its pdb to be found for and select Symbol Load Information

It should look in the same directory as your dll to begin with and if it finds the pdb will either load it or tell you that the pdb file doesn't match the dll.

I hope it will help you solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for information about Modules window, it shows that symbol file is correctly loaded.